# What is the difference between "transferred" and "resources" in Chrome DevTools Network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How these two data amounts, that are located at the bottom of Network Tab differ?

[image]

Answer (score 262, accepted):

"Transferred" is the compressed size of all resources. You can think of it as the amount of upload and download data that a mobile user will use in order to load this page. "Resources" is the uncompressed size of all resources.

Comment: Just add a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm still not sure how to understand this. My understanding now: "Let's say I visit a website, then I download X amount of compressed data. After download this data is uncompressed by Chrome, and then used to display the page". Is this how I should think about this?

Comment: @wOxxOm that will probably do the trick, I’ll add a note to investigate further.

Comment: I filed a feature request to improve our tooltips: https://crbug.com/961389

Comment: Maybe rename "resources" to "uncompressed". So you'd have one value for "transferred" and one for "uncompressed", that would make it way clearer for me.

Comment: "Uncompressed" or "Actual Size"

Comment: Ended up here looking for the same... A tooltip would be helpful. The world "Resources" is definitely going to confuse a lot of people. Ideally you just call it what it is. "Uncompressed". Better yet, add an optional column in the Network tab for each resource, maybe call it "Uncompressed Size"

Comment: Just adding my little comment, confirming that as things are, it's quite cryptic. A different label ("transferred" and "uncompressed"), or a tooltip, would be very helpful :)

Comment: _"Question: Can you all think of better words to describe these two values? We get this question somewhat often."_ If this is an annoying question you can freely choose not to answer it. This is not the first time I see behaviors like this comming from Google employees.

Comment: I like the fact that Google is asking for feedback. I'd suggest "transferred" and "transferred (uncompressed)". The brackets makes it clear these numbers are related, at the moment that isn't clear

Comment: Or. "transferred 10mb (uncompressed 23mb)"

Comment: I like the WebPageTest approach: Bytes In (downloaded) VS
Uncompressed Size

Comment: Cool, I thought I recognized your image and then remembered in these vids: https://youtu.be/fJxFZO8OEEs
You're great in explaining stuff @KayceBasques

Comment: upvote for 'transferred 10mb (uncompressed 23mb)', @KayceBasques is there a place that chrome documentation explains this? this is actually missing on https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference , you can add there, so we dont have to stackoverflow it here in 2020 ;), hahah just joking, happy coding guys!

Comment: Just leave it as it is... thankfully we got Stackoverflow

Comment: I thought "resources" included cached stuff.. The tooltipp "resources loaded by this map" is not helpful. Also I'm getting more numbers: 866 kb / 9.0MB transferred | 2.1 MB / 28.2 MB resources

Comment: just known about this, the first time I've seen a huge difference between the `Size` shown in the Network tab and the actual size of the downloaded file and I just thought that there was something wrong with my computer (maybe some virus caused it).

Comment: I love how they ask for suggestions of how to make it clearer, yet more than two years later it's still exactly the same.

Comment: @Heinzlmaen if you see two numbers in one column, it means you have some filters on which indicate size of filtered / size of all

Comment: Is there a need for me to even see the uncompressed size?

Comment: Uncompressing the data takes time and additionally slows down your WebPages

Comment: I knew this was the answer, but I still had to Google it to be sure after looking at it for a while. It's not very intuitive. "transferred" and "uncompressed" would've been clearer to me.

Comment: "Transferred" would be typically gzip-ed right?

Answer (score 9):

An important difference not mentioned in the other answers is that "resources" will include **any cached data**, whereas "transferred" (as the name implies) only shows the actual **downloaded data** when loading the page.

This can easily be verified by ticking the *Disable cache* checkbox in the toolbar on top of the request list - once enabled there is a considerable difference in filesize of "transferred" and "resources" (in addition to the difference caused by compression).

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers, if you have filtered the results you will see two numbers in one column, first one indicating the size for the filtered requests and the latter for the total size of requests.

For example if you have filtered the results to only display XHR requests and you see `1 MB / 2 MB transferred` at the bottom, that indicates 2 MB has been transferred in total, of which 1 MB are XHR requests.